# Odoo 9.0C: How can i access the value of a many2one field (that has been created in sale.order.line module on the invoice qweb report?

Tags: odoo-9, many-to-one, qweb

I have installed module Sale Sourced by Line
by Camptocamp, Eficent, SerpentCS, Odoo Community Association (OCA) for Odoo 9.0.
The module creates a new many2one field as the code bellow:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    warehouse_id = fields.Many2one(
        'stock.warehouse',
        'Source Warehouse',
        readonly=True,
        states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]},
        help="If a source warehouse is selected, "
             "it will be used to define the route. "
             "Otherwise, it will get the warehouse of "
             "the sale order")
```

Now i would like to access the value warehouse_id on account_invoice_report qweb. Please tell me what are posible solutions for my purpose? Thank for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **account.invoice.line** one field available **sale_line_ids**, based on that you can search **warehouse_id** from **sale.order.line**.

**invoice.invoice_line_ids.mapped('sale_line_ids').mapped('warehouse_id')**

This may help you.

Comment: @api.multi
    def _trigger_sale_line(self):
        for invoice_line in self:
            if invoice_line.sale_line_ids:
    invoice_line.warehouse_id = sale_line_ids.sale_line_ids[0].warehouse_id.id if invoice_line.sale_order_line_ids[0].warehouse_id else None

Comment: You can write it but there is one mistake sale_line_ids.sale_line_ids[0] is wrong. invoice_line.sale_line_ids and invoice_line.sale_line_ids[0] is correct.

Comment: yes that my mistake, so sitll i need to add the field to the invoice view ?

Comment: No you can create one field in account.invoice.line like : warehouse_id=invoice_line.sale_line_ids and invoice_line.sale_line_ids[0].warehouse_id or direct access in invoice without create any field in invoice , invoice.invoice_line_ids.mapped('sale_line_ids').mapped('warehouse_id')

Comment: could you please teach me how can i add the invoice_line.warehouse_id on the account_invoice report qweb.