# Odoo 9.0 C How to add a new many2one field from an inherited view?

Tags: view, odoo-9, qweb

Could you guy please show me what is the right steps to follow when we want to add a new many2one field to an inherited view like account.invoice.order.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the same :

```
  <template id="new_id" inherit_id="module_name.qweb_template_id" name="Template name as you want">
      <!-- specify the target that you want to add the many2one field
              than the place after,before or inside -->
        <xpath expr="//target_where_you_want_to_add" position="after/before/inside">
            <field name="your_one_to_many_field_name" />
        </xpath>
  </template>
```

the hard part is targeting the write place 
like if you want to add the the field to a div tag inside a div with id ="div_id" and the div contain a class="class_name"

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='div_id']/div[@class='class_name']" position="inside">
```

or a after a field inside that div named field1

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='div_id']/div[@class='class_name']/field[@name='field1']" position="after">
```

or after a field that named field1

```
 <!-- // is like a shortcut -->
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='field1']" position="after">
```

so see who can you target the place that you want to put the field using tag names and properties  like id,class,... (string is not supported in odoo 9)

Comment: Thank for replying to me, actually I would like to add a "Many2one" field  not one2many. On the other hand, this field alredy exist in sale.order.line and my final target is showing its value on the account invoice report qweb. Please take a minute to see the field that i have posted in other qwestion topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050684/odoo-9-0c-how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-many2one-field-that-has-been-created

Comment: hope this help you

Comment: Thanks you for all, i will try ito fix my module now, hope it work, have a nice day